# Sample Grails web app: upload file, process it, download

Tags: grails, web, groovy, process

I'm trying to make my first web app using Grails.

I want to upload a file, process it and return for download. I think it's a very common scheme and I believe there should be some sample app that does that.

I would like to use such and only change the processing part, implementing my own. It'd be the best if it was in Grails, but I guess anything else will work too. Well, the only problem might be that I have written my processing part in Groovy.

The help I'm seeking from you is whether you could provide me a source of such sample app/sample code/template so I could right away start implementing the processing part.

Obviously I've been searching for one to no avail.

I'm a newbie when it comes to web apps; I've only programmed some simple desktop apps, so if my question is inappropriate I'm terribly sorry.

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look to this guide: [How to upload a file with Grails 3](http://guides.grails.org/grails-upload-file/guide/index.html)

For a quick answer, the steps you would need to take are:

1. In a view, create a form using the `<g:uplodaForm>` tag and add an `<input type="file" name"myFile" />` element.
2. In the controller, get the file using `def myFile = request.getFile("myFile")`.
3. In a controller, to recover a file from the disk (assuming png image):

   ```
   File myFile = new File("/<file_path>/myFile")
   render file: myFile.newInputStream(), contentType: 'image/png'
   return
   ```